# Dapper - splitOn doesn't exist

Tags: stored-procedures, dapper

I'm trying to execute this snippet

```
var dParams = new DynamicParameters();

dParams.Add("@ShipDate", warranty.ShipDate);
dParams.Add("@WarrantyStartDate", warranty.WarrantyStartDate);
dParams.Add("@WarrantyEndDate", warranty.WarrantyEndDate);
dParams.Add("@SerialNumber", warranty.SerialNumber);

var result = conn.Query<Warranty>("TMP_WARRANTY_INFORMATION_insert", dParams ,commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
```

But then it says "When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id", so I try to add a splitOn parameter, but I can't seem to do it according to how the docs/internet says it should, and intellisense can't find the param.

Am I doing something wrong or is it Dapper?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I switched from .Query to .Execute, and changed some of the params

```
var dParams = new DynamicParameters();

 dParams.Add("@ShipDate", warranty.ShipDate, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
 dParams.Add("@WarrantyStartDate", warranty.WarrantyStartDate, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
 dParams.Add("@WarrantyEndDate", warranty.WarrantyEndDate, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
 dParams.Add("@SerialNumber", warranty.SerialNumber, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);

  var result = conn.Execute("TMP_WARRANTY_INFORMATION_insert", dParams ,commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: odd; does the SP return a grid of data?

Comment: I'm doing an "INSERT INTO [TABLE] SELECT x0, x1 .. xN FROM [TABLE]" in my SP

Comment: Oh, ok :P The example of how to use a SP on https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ was using Query<T> so thats why I was using it

Comment: That is because the example there **returns a grid**. The deciding factor is not "is this query a stored procedure?" - it is "does it return a grid of data?". And `INSERT` (at least, without the `OUTPUT` clause) *does not*.